# Vertical align button beside image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my link to vertical align center in the middle and my logo to vertical align in the middle but off to the right as the image below shows. I can get the image to work perfectly. but i cannot get the link vertical aligned middle.

this will also be full width across.

[image: view layout image]

```css
.footer-logo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px; 
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.footer-main {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(../images/backgrounds/bg-image.jpg);
  background-color: grey; 
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-main">
  <a class="button" href="#">My test link here</a>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="" class="footer-logo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no `top-margin` in CSS only `margin-top` or `top`

**OPTION A** use `display:flex` on the container , `#footer` in this case, together with `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`

where `align-items` aligns the items inside the flexbox **vertically** 
and `justify-content` aligns them **horizonally**

***DOCs:***

- **[display:flex](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)**
- **[align-items](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp)**
- **[justify-content](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp)**

**OPTION B** ( *after comments* ) seems like in firefox, applying `align-items:center` doesn't affect an element with `position:absolute;` so i've added `transform:translateY(-50%)` together with `top:50%` on the logo.

this works because , top:50% reffers to 50% of the footers height, and translateY(-50%) refers to 50% of the logo's height , so basically you move from top to bottom the logo with 50% of the footer height, then move it back up with 50% of it's own height and the result is that it is vertically centered.

**OPTION C**

using `display:inline-block` together with `vertical-align:middle` on the `.footer-logo` will also work.

**OPTION D**

one more option would be to use `top:calc(50% - 50px)` on the `.footer-logo` but this works only if the height of the logo stays constant. it's not recommended to use this method but it's a good use of the `calc()` CSS function

you choose ;)

```css
.footer-logo {
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: 50px;   
transform: translateY(-50%);
top:50%;

}

.footer-main {
height: 200px;
background-color: grey; 
position: relative;



  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-main">
<a class="button" href="#">My test link here</a>
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x100" alt="" class="footer-logo">
</div>
```

Comment: @mihai-tlook at my image.. the button looks good now but the logo is not in the middle

Comment: @DataDev   be sure to delete the margin-top:30px as i did in my code.

Comment: @mihai-tlook if you run your code snip the image is aligned at the bottom not the middle

Comment: @DataDev hmm seems like you use firefox and in firefox, vertical centering of an `absolute` element doesn't work with `align-items` so, i've changed the solution using translate and top. let me know if it works now